# How to set up a local SMTP server for sending mail using pythons smtplib module

Tags: python, email, smtp

I want to create a program ,which can send bulk emails to people (for company purposes).
For a few emails I used gmail.smtp.com for sending mails

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  
# start TLS for security
#s.starttls()
  
# Authentication
s.login("myemail@gmail.com","mypassword")
  
# message to be sent
message="hello"
# sending the mail
s.sendmail("myemail@gmail.com", "targetemail@gmail.com", message)
  
# terminating the session
print("mail sent")
s.quit()
```

I know that I cannot use Gmail's SMTP server for sending bulk mail.
How do I set up a local SMTP server and use it in smtplib?